# What is the right usage for the SingleSelectionModel?

Tags: gwt

we would like to link from a CellTable to a property editor page. We use the SingleSelectionModel to get notified, when a user clicks on an item.
It is initialized like this:

```
private final SingleSelectionModel<Device> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Device>();
```

We then assign the selection change handler:

```
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(this);
```

Our selection change handler looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
    Log.debug("DevicesPresenter:  SelectionChangeEvent caught.");
    Device selectedDevice = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
    if (selectedDevice != null) {
        selectionModel.clear();
        if (selectionModel.getSelectedObject() != null){
            Log.debug("DevicesPresenter:  selected item is " + selectionModel.getSelectedObject());
        }
        else{
            Log.debug("DevicesPresenter:  selected item is null");
        }

        deviceEditorDialog.setCurrentDevice(selectedDevice.getUuid());
        // get the container data for this device
        clientModelProvider.fetchContainersForDevice(selectedDevice.getUuid());
        PlaceRequest request = new PlaceRequest.Builder()
        .nameToken(NameTokens.deviceInfo)
        .with("uuid", selectedDevice.getUuid())
        .build();
        Log.debug("Navigating to " + request.toString());
        placeManager.revealPlace(request);
    }
}
```

Now there are two issues: There always seem to be two SelectionChangeEvents at once and i really cannot see why. The other thing is: How is the right way do handle selection of items and the related clearing of the selection model? Do we do that the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get notified of "clicks" without keeping the "clicked" item selected, use a `NoSelectionModel` instead; no need to clear the selection model as soon as something is selected.

As for your other issue with being called twice, double-check that you haven't added your selection handler twice (if you can unit-test your `DevicesPresenter`, introspect the handlers inside the selection model for example)

Comment: Thank you for the hint to the NoSelectionModel. That is exactly what we need. We tried that before without succes, but there was some mistake at our side...

Answer (score 0):

In your line `selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(this);` what does **this** refer?

Here my code how I use `SingleSelectionModel`

```
public class MyClass{
        private final SingleSelectionModel<CountryDto> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<CountryDto>();
    ...
public MyClass(){
         cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
         selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
                                CountryDto selected = selectionModel
                                        .getSelectedObject();
                                if (selected != null) {
                                    Window.alert("Selected country "+selected.getTitle());
                                }
                            }
                        });
}
}
```

Comment: Try to use `event.stopPropagation();`